# Show value of Multi dimension Array in php

Tags: php, arrays

i want to display multi dimensional array in php to show all the array values in html i want to show these values : coupon_link,coupon_description,store, expire_date.Please Suggest me how to show array in tabular format  sample here below

```
    Array
(
    [status_code] => 200
    [status_text] => Success
    [count] => 183
    [data] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [coupon_urlh] => 02940b49613d6588f538d6c22feaf12a142d63ab
                    [coupon_title] => 
                    [coupon_code] => 
                    [coupon_description] => Get the Motorola Nexus 6 starting at Rs. 34,999. No coupon code required.
                    [published_date] => 
                    [expiry_date] => 
                    [last_tested] =>    Verified Today
                    [success_rate] => 
                    [crawl_time] => 20150630110739
                    [coupon_link] => http://dl.flipkart.com/dl/mobiles/pr?p[0]=facets.brand[]=Motorola&p[1]=facets.availability[]=Exclude Out of Stock&sid=tyy,4io&filterNone=true&q=nexus 6&affid=contact&affExtParam1=p:rQd1Du50OXFe
                    [store] => Flipkart
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [coupon_urlh] => 0753512477c9d48369590db9670d16063b9e9b7b
                    [coupon_title] => 
                    [coupon_code] => 
                    [coupon_description] => Get minimum 50% off on books displayed on the landing page. No coupon code required.
                    [published_date] => 
                    [expiry_date] => 
                    [last_tested] =>    Verified Today
                    [success_rate] => 
                    [crawl_time] => 20150630110822
                    [coupon_link] => http://dl.flipkart.com/dl/books/~selected-general-books/pr?p[0]=facets.discount_range[]=More than 50%&sid=bks&filterNone=true&affid=contact&affExtParam1=p:cCPZiRc86rkW
                    [store] => Flipkart
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [coupon_urlh] => 0aff177f5e76bf20ab00c55fd4f8a8f30332de08
                    [coupon_title] => 
                    [coupon_code] => 
                    [coupon_description] => Get minimum 50% off on sunglasses.
                    [published_date] => 
                    [expiry_date] => 
                    [last_tested] =>    Verified Today
                    [success_rate] => 
                    [crawl_time] => 20150630110831
                    [coupon_link] => http://dl.flipkart.com/dl/sunglasses/pr?p[0]=facets.discount_range[]=More than 50%&sid=26x&affid=contact&affExtParam1=p:y3x7w6O3TkL0
                    [store] => Flipkart
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [coupon_urlh] => 16249e29e9b70776e9713d8a88c6854d9e315080
                    [coupon_title] => 
                    [coupon_code] => 
                    [coupon_description] => Get minimum 50% off on car accessories. No coupon code required.
                    [published_date] => 
                    [expiry_date] => 
                    [last_tested] =>    Verified Today
                    [success_rate] => 
                    [crawl_time] => 20150630110806
                    [coupon_link] => http://dl.flipkart.com/dl/offers/car-accessories?affid=contact&affExtParam1=p:FLlJjJezfFPq
                    [store] => Flipkart
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [coupon_urlh] => 17bc8b23813a0cdaa07c2da63412831a3c7fc615
                    [coupon_title] => 
                    [coupon_code] => 
                    [coupon_description] => Deals of The Day: Avail exciting offers everyday on various categories. No coupon code required.
                    [published_date] => 
                    [expiry_date] => 
                    [last_tested] =>    Verified Today
                    [success_rate] => 
                    [crawl_time] => 20150630110729
                    [coupon_link] => http://dl.flipkart.com/dl/offers?affid=contact&affExtParam1=p:bewu0vDGfKyd
                    [store] => Flipkart
                )

        )

)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [foreach loop](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) in `php`.

```
foreach($your_array['data'] as $element){
    echo $element['coupon_description']."<br />";
    echo $element['store']."<br />";
    .....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access seeked values by doing:

```
// retrieve the coupon description for the first element of your array
echo $array['data'][0]['coupon_description'];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use the function `print_r` in PHP (http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) you can return a human readable format of the variable. This function will show exactly what you displayed in your question. The only problem is HTML will not parse the tabs, new lines, and spaces. BUT if you use the HTML tag `<pre>` it will do just that.

So I actually use this bit of code for debugging variables all the time. I actually made a short cut for it in PHPStorm for even faster debugging:

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($data);
echo '</pre>';
die("Debug in file " . __FILE__ . ':' . __LINE__);
```

so if $data is `array('hey', 'there', 'cool', 'kid', array('how', 'are', 'you'))` then this will output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => hey
    [1] => there
    [2] => cool
    [3] => kid
    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => how
            [1] => are
            [2] => you
        )

)

Debug in file /var/www/vhosts/test.local/test.php:10
```

This does not only work for arrays. You can use this on basically all variables. It is extremely helpful when parsing responses from APIs or other systems that return very long responses.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of Multi dimensional Array:

```
$cars = array
  (
  array("Volvo",22,18),
  array("BMW",15,13),
  array("Saab",5,2),
  array("Land Rover",17,15)
  );
```

With out a **`foreach`** **loop** you can echo an *Multi dimensional*  array like this:

```
for ($row = 0; $row < 4; $row++) {
  echo "<p><b>Row number $row</b></p>";
  echo "<ul>";
  for ($col = 0; $col < 3; $col++) {
    echo "<li>".$cars[$row][$col]."</li>";
  }
  echo "</ul>";
}
```